# How to display message before redirecting to another page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem... I have registration form and when user has registred it redirect him to Home page..i want to display popup message before redirecting him that he is successfuly registred and then redirect him to Home page.

Controller:

```
  TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "A confirmation email will be sent to the address you've entered shortly";        
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

View:

```
<script>
 if (@TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
  {
    alert('@TempData["SuccessMessage"]');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You will need to use ajax to post the registration data, then in the ajax success callback, display a message. Alternatively do a normal post and redirect to a view that displays your message and from there redirect to the home page. But why not just display the message on the home page?

Comment: that would be much easier...tnx :)

Comment: How can i set redirect to another page after some interval if i use r solution?

Comment: Are your referring to the the second one? If so I would just have an 'OK' button/link on the message page so when the user clicks it it then redirects to the home page (let the user control what they want do do - you should not be controlling them)

Comment: can i use this   <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10;URL=@(Url.Action("Index", "Home"))"> ??

Comment: And what happens when just as the user submits the form, the phone rings - the user might never see your message DON'T DO IT! Let the user control there own actions.

Comment: _"Use of meta refresh is discouraged by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C), since unexpected refresh can disorient users"_ ([from here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh))

Answer (score 0):

store redirect url Like this way

```
ViewBag.Redirect = "Your URL ";
```

And do java script mention below

```
<script>
        if (@TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
        {
            alert('@TempData["SuccessMessage"]');

            window.setTimeout(function () {
                location.href = @ViewBag.Redirect;
            }, 5000);

        }   

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your script in the Layout view page instance of your view page, which allows you to send messages from any Controllers to all views using the same layout.
moreover, using Tempdata not viewbag because Tempdata allows you to keep data between controllers but viewbag will be cleared after redirecting to another controller.

```
<script>
 if (@TempData["SuccessMessage"] != null)
  {
    alert('@TempData["SuccessMessage"]');
  }
</script>
```